# C# function more vice-functions

Tags: c#, function, class

I want to make an .dll file for me to make my job easier, but I want to make invites look like `CLASS.FUNCTION.FOO.BAR()` but i can only make it to look like `CLASS.Function()`.

```
public static class CLASS {
    public static void Fuction_name() {
      //What do I have to write here for it?
    }
}
```

What do you think I should do?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a Fluent-like syntax for your class?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this:

```
public class CarModelBuilder()
{
    // prevent from creating this directly
    private CarModelBuilder()
    {
    }

    public static CarModelBuilder Build()
    {
         return new CarModelBuilder();
    }

    public CarModelBuilder Wheel(Wheel wheel)
    {
         // add wheel here
         return this;
    }

    public CarModelBuilder Door(Door door)
    {
         // add door here
         return this;
    }

    public CarModelBuilder Engine(Engine engine)
    {
         // add engine here
         return this;
    }

    // etc

    // completion
    public Car Complete() 
    {
         // complete modelling here
         return new Car();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var car = CarModelBuilder
    .Build()
    .Wheel(new Wheel())
    .Door(new Door())
    .Engine(new Engine())
    // more spare parts here
    .Complete();
```

?

Comment: No, but it's something. I mean Arraythinghs.Count.primes or positives. But thanks.